# Can we use/import casperjs in chrome extension or chrome console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, casperjs, browserify

I am aware of [resurrectio](https://github.com/ebrehault/resurrectio) project which does something different. What I'd like to know is if one can "import" casper in a chrome extension (via browserify for example)?

Say we'd like to run this [example](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/master/samples/each.js) inside chrome extension. How would we go about doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CasperJS is built on top of PhantomJS which itself runs not on node.js. PhantomJS is a complete (headless) browser, so it cannot be executed directly in another browser.

You could implement the CasperJS API as a Chrome extension and drive tabs with it, but that's a big task. You don't need that at all for the example you linked. You can get each of the remote DOMs with jQuery's `$.get()` and use `$.parseHTML()` on them and iterate to find the element that you look for.